# The included URLconf '…\blog\urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns.If you see valid patterns then the issue is caused by a circular import

Tags: python, django

[image]

[image]

The detailed error is as follows

```
(base) C:\Users\USER\Documents\Django Tutorial\django_blog>python manage.py runserver Watching for file changes with StatReloader Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 586, in url_patterns
    iter(patterns)
**TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable**

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 67, in _load_all_namespaces
    namespaces.extend(_load_all_namespaces(pattern, current))   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 593, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name)) django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: **The included URLconf '<module 'blog.urls' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\Documents\\Django Tutorial\\django_blog\\blog\\urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.**
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at some other Django questions (search for `[django]`) and how they are formatted, then [edit] your question to add your code as code and not as pictures of code. Thanks.

Comment: typo，not ulrpaths

Answer (score 0):

The variable name in urls.py has to be **urlpatterns** and not urlpaths.